# Connecting prototypecell to different scenes using storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using storyboard to connect my prototype cell to a scene, a cell in my table view will lead to a different scene using segue, my question is can I do it using storyboard because through storyboard I am able to connect prototype cell to one scene only.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261048/ios-firing-multiple-segues-from-a-prototype-cell-in-storyboards)

Looks like you need to add the segue from you Table View Controller to your destination view controllers instead of from your cell. Then you can do something like this in your Table View Cell

```
tableview(tableview, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath) {
    if shouldSeguaToSceneAWithIndexPath(indexPath) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueA")
    else if shouldSeguaToSceneBWithIndexPath(indexPath)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueB")
    else if shouldSeguaToSceneCWithIndexPath(indexPath)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueC")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers Jonathan and Bhavin, both of you have provided with similar approach to solve this but the data in my Tableview is dynamic so indexpath is not going to help.

Comment: in what sense are you saying that the data is  dynamic ? There must be something that differentiates the data to be passed to  two  different view controllers. if nothing works then create two different prototype cells and segue appropriately!