# Receiver MainVIewController has no segue iOS

Tags: ios, segue

**Question was solved! See the code at the bottom.**

I'd like to pass some data between 2 controllers. I have MainViewController class where GoogleMap is loaded. On click at custom info window for each GMap's marker I want to open new window with place details. 
My storyboard is:
[image: Storyboard]

Segue was named: showPlaceDetails:

[image: Segue]

Several methods was written:

```
- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showPlaceDetails" sender: nil];
}
```

(I also tried to use `sender: [marker snippet]`).

My prepareForSegue method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPlaceDetails"]) {
        //[[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
        PlaceDetailsViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        //Pass some data
    }
}
```

But I got the message: 
**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (RelaxInKZViewController) has no segue with identifier 'showPlaceDetails''**

I did these steps:

1. Add New View Controller on storyboard.
2. Add Objective-C Class called PlaceDetailsViewController.
3. Change custom class of newly added VC to "PlaceDetailsViewController"
4. Add that code
5. Clear Simulator's data and clean project

And nothing. I hope you can help me :)
Thx, Artem.

---

Mr_bem has adviced me to refuse segues and use pushViewController method. It's good!

```
UIStoryboard *iPhoneStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    PlaceDetailsViewController *destViewController = [iPhoneStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlaceDetailsViewController"];
    destViewController.placeData = marker.placeData;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:destViewController animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a Push segue, this can only be performed with a navigationController, like:

```
[self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showPlaceDetails" sender: nil];
```

Note you should have a navigation controller before your ViewController, the one that pushes.

Or if you want, you can change its type to Modal, everything should work great for you (Y)

**UPDATE**

Okay, here's what I propose, remove the segue, make the storyboardID of your PlaceDetailsViewController to PlaceDetailsViewController from the IB, and add this code instead

```
    - (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {
        PlaceDetailsViewController *destViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlaceDetailsViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:destViewController animated:YES]
se
    }
```

THIS MUST WORK! LOL!

Comment: Did you add a navigationController to your storyBoard and then make RelaxInKZViewController its root view controller? If you did this, the code I provided should work.. Or just change the type of the segue to modal.


And yes, what you are doing is correct, just a small mistake, once fixed, it should be awesome!

Comment: Hold on control key, then drag from the navigation controller, to your RelaxInKZViewController, then chose segue type 'Root controller'. And thats it, use the code provided in my answer and you should be good to go (Y)

Comment: Try to delete the '.navigationController' ?

Comment: Oh awesome! Actually its the same. You are just creating a segue programatically... Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed your `RelaxInKZViewController` inside `UINavigationController` to use `push` `segue`. Select RelaxInKZViewController-> from the menu at the top select `Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller`. I think that will solve your problem.

Comment: Error is still alive :( http://s18.postimg.org/eo85ky76h/2013_11_25_14_34_32.png - It's my storyboard now.

Comment: try cleaning the project and run again also reset the simulator settings.

Comment: this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874200/nsinvalidargumentexception-receiver-has-no-segue-with-identifier

Comment: try removing the segue and add it again. or alternatively you use [self.navigationController pushViewController:animated:] method in the didTapInfoWindowOfMarker: method to push next viewcontroller, it doesn't require segue.